# Solving diophantine equation $ax + by = d$ with $(x,b) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose I have linear diophantine equation $ax + by = d,$ where $(a,b) = d.$

I think I can prove that there exists solution with $(x,b) = 1$ through chinese remainder theorem.

Can it be proven in more direct way?

Answer (score 1):

Why will you need Chinese remainder theorem? You use the Chinese remainder theorem when you want to solve a system of congruences in different moduli where the given moduli are relatively prime.

You can prove the existence of a solution by using Bézout's theorem on $\gcd$.
I have proved it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492864/demonstracao-do-teorema-de-bezout-proof-of-bezouts-theorem/493056#493056).
By using this theorem you can easily prove that the linear diophantine equation $ax+by=d$ has integers solutions if and only if $(x,b) \mid d$.

Comment: But I need special type of solution - with $(x,b) = 1$.

Comment: @ptashek: Would you please explain what you mean by 'special' type of solution with $(x,b) = 1$?

Comment: So the problem is: prove that for fixed $a,b$ exists $x$ with $(x,b) = 1,$ such that exists $y,$ such that $ax + by = (a,b).$ I can prove it with chinese remainder theorem. And the question is - could it be explained in more direct way?

Comment: Wait. Now I see what your question is I think. Are you assuming that $ax+by=d$ already has solutions in integers and then you want to show that $(x,b)=1$?

Comment: No, I want to show that such $x$ exists.